# scrollup uitablviewcell partially visible

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, contentoffset

I need some help.

- That i want to scrollup uitalbeview cell which is partially
  displaying.See screen shot.
- Here my tableview has a three section and u can see that in morning
  section the row is displaying partially.I just want to move up that
  kind of row.

[image]

- I tried content offset but not getting any idea that how to get first
  visible row offset so,i can calculate and move it up or down

.
Note: not for bottom row only top rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of a UITableView. The section headers will stick at the top of the screen until the next section header will reach it. One easy work around is to not use headers at all and simply use two cells. You would then have to add code in your viewForCellAtIndexPath:

```
if(indexPath.row == 0) {
     //setup a header cell
} else {
     //setup a data cell
}
```